# Install Ubuntu to PC based Tablet

Tags: 14.04, dell, touchscreen, tablet

I have Dell Venue Pro 8 tablet which originally use Win8.1. I try to install Ubuntu to it, should I just download and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS? And will 14.04 have touch screen support?

Joe

Comment: Yes it has touch support out of the box, you can find a keyboard in `settings, universal access` its called `onboard` and you can click the little man symbol on the log in screen to start `onboard` if you need to log in.

Comment: While you can (and should) try Ubuntu **14.04** on an Intel-based tablet PC (designed to run Win 8.1), this is not a currently supported platform for '**ubuntu-touch**'. This (Ubuntu Touch) is still in beta and only supports specific smartphones (or similar tablets, but with phone-centric UI).